# Meteor-App: Tracker is not defined

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a meteor-package like this:

```
Package.describe({
    name: 'name:anything',
    summary: 'example package',
    version: '0.0.1',
    documentation: "README.md"
});

Package.onUse(function(api){
    api.versionsFrom('METEOR@1.1.0.3');

    api.use(['templating', 'mongo']);
    api.use(['iron:router@1.0.9'], 'client');

    api.addFiles(['lib/client/anything.js'], ['client']);

    api.export('App');

});
```

In `lib/client/anything.js` I wrote the lines

```
App = {};
App.Mode = {};
App.Mode._dep = new Tracker.Dependency();
```

I added the anything.js file in the package.js and I export the app-var - like you see it above.

But I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Tracker is not defined`

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: where are you importing tracker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tracker` package needs to be `api.use`d in your package to be able to reference `Tracker`.

```
api.use(['templating', 'mongo', 'tracker']);
```